# Relationship of SQL and NoSQL entities in Symfony

Tags: mysql, mongodb, symfony, doctrine, model-associations

I use symfony on my web page, I want to use both `mongodb` and `mysql` in my database model, and i don't know how to link between a table on my sql and a document on mongodb.
Example: `PERSON` -- relation 1--n -- `ADDRESS`, where `PERSON` is a table on my `mysql` database and `ADDRESS` is a document on `mongodb`.
Is it possible? How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think the original question unclear, though I had to make some assumptions toward current and default methods to be able to answer. OP, please clarify if these are incorrect! 1) Usage of Symfony2. 2) DB model is handled by Doctrine. 3) You already know that you cannot set a connection on the DB level, and the question is about handling the relation with PHP or ORM code. 4) You are not stuck on a specific part of implementing but do not know in general whether/how to approach the problem.

Comment: Then I suggest this question no longer be on hold. @simON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible if you want to have as strong a relation as e.g. foreign key constraints. The two databases will never have immediate knowledge of each other's data, transactions (!), scopes, etc. You can carefully write code that synchronizes the two. One approach I find easy and reliable: (for the reference, documents are data block of NoSQL [entities in NoSQL] while records are data items of SQL [entities in SQL])

1. All documents are children of one record (or not transaction-safe).
2. All transactions are controlled by SQL.
3. Locking a record for writing implies locking all child documents.
4. Updating a document requires the parent record to be locked.
5. One NoSQL transaction (if the feature is available) is nested right inside any SQL transacion.
6. DB cross-references are simple data; don't expect either the DB or Doctrine to handle them specially.

In this manner the two databases can be used in sync, relatively safely with transactions and locking.